# How can i disable the default NodeTypes in TYPO3 Neos?

Tags: neoscms

How can i disable the default NodeTypes without deleting the package TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes?

If i delete this package i also have to delete the package TYPO3.Neos.Kickstarter because it depends on the NodeType package.

I tried set autoinclude to false in the TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes Settings.yaml but it doesn't work.

```
TYPO3:
  Neos:
    typoScript:
      autoInclude:
        'TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes': False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to mark node types as abstract, then they won't show up in the user interface.

NodeTypes.yaml:

```
'TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:Headline':
  abstract: TRUE
```

alternatively:

```
'TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:Headline':
  ui: ~
```

Comment: Hej Aske.
Any news on this one?And can you give a brief example of how to achieve that?

Comment: See official documentation to understand the difference between Aske's two options: https://docs.neos.io/cms/manual/content-repository/nodetype-definition#disable-existing-nodetypes

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to remove the *Headline* node type from the list of node types available to add to a document:

```
'TYPO3.Neos.NodeTypes:Headline': []
```

I put this line into the NodeTypes.yaml of my site package.